# Is "degrees" singular or plural?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I was talking to native. They corrected me and said that usually we use "is" with degrees. For example:

> There **is** 27 degrees here.

And we shouldn't use it like that:

> There **are** 27 degrees here.

Is it true? Is here some rule for that...? Cause I don't get it. For me, degrees is plural. Why should we use "is" here?

Comment: In the US, at least, you wouldn't say "There is 27 degrees" but rather "It is 27 degrees".

Comment: There's also the consideration that implicilty the noun that the verb is agreeing with is "termperature" rather than "degrees"

Comment: @user888379 Please write an answer, not a comment.

Comment: I don't have an authoritative source to cite, I'm afraid.

Comment: Do you mean degrees Farenheit/Celcius/Kelvin or do you mean degrees of arc?

Comment: _estamos a 40 grados aquí_ is normal in Spanish; maybe that's where the confusion comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Degree" is a count noun. The singular form is "a [*or* one] degree" and the plural is "degrees." This is true for both temperature and geometry.

But when discussing the temperature at some place, we do not say "There are XX degrees here." Instead we *describe the temperature* (which is a singular noun):

> *The temperature* here is 27 degrees.
> *It is* 27 degrees here.

So that may be why the person you were talking to associated the singular form of the verb **to be** with the plural noun "degrees."